# R markdown can't identify '#' and ' ``` 'in part of my file

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm doing my homework in Rmarkdown. And in the middle part of my file, '##' suddenly can't be identified and the code can't show in a block normally.

It should show as below:

```
summary(dat1$Capital.Ch)
```

```
dat1[dat1$Capital.Ch == "高纬度",]$Disused.Dynasty2
```

```
##  任务四  
请构造一个多元线性回归模型，并用summary给出回归分析的结果，要对你的模型结果有具体的解读。  

#### 建立回归模型
```

```
reg = lm(log(Age) ~ Dynasty.Age + Ascend.Age + is.Han + Father.Age + Num.Son + isnot.Unite + Num.War + as.factor(Capital.Ch), data = dat1)
summary(reg)
```

But in fact, when I click 'knit', '##' and '```' can't be identified and they all appear in the HTML. But other parts of my file appear normally. I guess there may be something wrong with the regression codes?
They are just like this:

`r summary(dat1$Capital.Ch)`
`## 低纬度 高纬度 中纬度 ## 52 12 147`
`r dat1[dat1$Capital.Ch="=" "高纬度",]$Disused.Dynasty2`

````
```  ## 任务四 请构造一个多元线性回归模型，并用summary给出回归分析的结果，要对你的模型结果有具体的解读。 #### 建立回归模型   

    reg="lm(log(Age)" ~ Dynasty.Age + Ascend.Age + is.Han + Father.Age + Num.Son + isnot.Unite + Num.War + as.factor(Capital.Ch), data="dat1)" summary(reg) 

    Call:  
    ## lm(formula="log(Age)" ~ Dynasty.Age + Ascend.Age + is.Han + Father.Age +  
    ## Num.Son + isnot.Unite + Num.War + as.factor(Capital.Ch),  
    ## data="dat1)" ##  
    ## Residuals:  
    ## Min 1Q Median 3Q Max  
    ## -2.6082 -0.1695 0.0008 0.1593 1.1257 
    ##  
    ## Coefficients:  
    ## Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
    ## (Intercept) 2.0309644 0.1940045 10.469 < 2e-16  
    ## Dynasty.Age 0.0013427 0.0004529 2.965 0.003478  
    ## Ascend.Age 0.0223336 0.0028501 7.836 5.41e-13  
    ## is.Han 0.0003991 0.0801790 0.005 0.996034
    ## Father.Age 0.0040405 0.0024145 1.673 0.096140 .
    ## Num.Son 0.0162578 0.0046628 3.487 0.000627  
    ## isnot.Unite 0.3029211 0.0941552 3.217 0.001558  
    ## Num.War 0.0093379 0.0014728 6.340 2.11e-09  
    ## as.factor(Capital.Ch)高纬度 0.2948875 0.1748353 1.687 0.093559 .
    ## as.factor(Capital.Ch)中纬度 0.1952361 0.0999606 1.953 0.052496 .
    ## — ## Signif. codes: 0 ‘’ 0.001 ’’ 0.01 ’’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘’ 1  
    ##  
    ## Residual standard error: 0.396 on 165 degrees of freedom  
    ## (36 observations deleted due to missingness)  
    ## Multiple R-squared: 0.5882, Adjusted R-squared: 0.5658 
    ## F-statistic: 26.19 on 9 and 165 DF, p-value: < 2.2e-16 ```
````

Comment: Please format your question properly. I struggle to understand what's prose and what's code in your post.

Comment: This is one of the few times where a picture would actually be better than text

Comment: Carol, one hint with including r-markdown chunks within SO markdown formatting: when you add the `\`\`\`{r blockname}`, for the entire r-markdown chunk, indent it 4 spaces (highlight, press `Ctrl-K`). That way, you actually show rmd code chunks properly.